# In Jenkins plugin developement, what is the Stapler (org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler)?

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am trying to create a simple jenkins plug-in that will run a job but `Project.doBuild()` requires `StaplerRequest` and `StaplerResponse`.

What is the `Stapler (org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler)`, `StaplerRequest(org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest)`, and `StaplerResponse(org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse)`? What do they do and how do they work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out http://stapler.kohsuke.org

> Stapler is a library that "staples" your application objects to URLs, making it easier to write web applications. The core idea of Stapler is to automatically assign URLs for your objects, creating an intuitive URL hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! that looks helpful.  Is there any reason doBuild() needs that hough?

Comment: @user833970: If this answer was what you were looking for, the way to accept it is to click the check mark beside the answer.